# Solr multiple cores?

Tags: solr

I have two cores with separate data, TV show, and Episode Data. When I search I want to present the user with both names of tv shows and episodes that match their query.

If I run a query on each core separately, I suppose my biggest issue is normalizing the scoring/sort of the results? For example, maybe the top 3 shows are much better matches then the first episode, how do I know how to merge these two results, I presume I don't? What if they are run on the same fields only? Will the results be "Objective"? Like if they were run on one core?

Can I run one query on two cores (it appears not). Would you run two different queries and try to merge results, or would you force both collections into one massive core, and have a field "mediaType"?

Comment: Either option works, but it usually depends on how you want to present the data - if you want a unified search that "this is the best match regardless of type", indexing everything into a single core would probably work best. If you want to display the three matching shows first, then matching episodes, using two cores works fine. You'll probably have to try both and experiment a bit to find out what works for you.

Comment: @MatsLindh Is there a way to know if the two separate query's scores are comparable?

Comment: No, not really. When you have everything in the same core, the scores will be affected by every document from both sides, while they won't when in different cores. However, the scores by themselves doesn't really have any meaning, and thus, can't be compared to each other (and there is normalizing taking place in some features, etc.). In general, you'll have to test - if you want the results interspersed, you a single core for everything and apply boosts as you see fit after testing and evaluating.

Comment: You can achieve it by using Joins. Solr provide join queries which can help you apply your query and filter on 2 cores. Beware it will make query a bit slow same as sql joins.